# didSelect mapView annotation not working properly

Tags: ios, mkmapview, swift4, mkannotation, mkannotationview

When I tap the map annotation it will display the more information about the pin.

On my first tap attempt ,when I tap the map annotation it will run successfully and it will display the correct information but when I hit back button and do my second tap attempt to the same pin the fatal error occured and its saying that 'Unexpectedly Found nil while unwrapping and optional value',

based on my observation and I made some troubleshooting and debugging, I found out that the fatal error only occurred when I didn't tap to the map first before I tap the map pin OR if I don't tap different pin (if I tap the same pin for the second attempt without tapping the map first error occurred)

`MyAnnotations` Class:

```
import MapKit

class MyAnnotations: NSObject,MKAnnotation{

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var img: String?
    var court_id: Int?
    var class_name: String?

    init(coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: 
    String?, img:String?, court_id: Int?, class_name: String?){
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.img = img
        self.court_id = court_id
        self.class_name = class_name

        super.init()
    }
}
```

My `func mapView(_:didSelect:)`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
    let ibp = view.annotation as? MyAnnotations
    print(ibp!)
    ibp_id = (ibp?.court_id)!
    IdentifierCell = "pin_IBP"
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "map_ibp_info", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the "Unexpectedly found nil" message? If it's at `print(ibd!)`, then you have to figure out why (e.g. `print(view.annotation)` and see what it was if not your custom `MyAnnotations` [sic]). If it's at the forced unwrapping of `court_id`, you need to figure out why it was `nil`. But we can't diagnose the problem on the basis of the information provided, only suggest that you (a) identify precisely which line is giving you that "unexpected found nil" message; and (b) track backwards to figure out how that possibly could happen (undoubtedly in code not included here).

Comment: yeah it's from `print(ibd!)`

Comment: So `print(view.annotation)` and see what that is. See why the cast failed.

Comment: <MKUserLocation: 0x60000023f720> @Rob

Comment: That means you tapped on the user location. So add a line at the beginning `if view.annotation is MKUserLocation { return }`. Basically, tell it to return immediately if it is a `MKUserLocation`. Or you can do `guard let ibp = view.annotation as? MyAnnotations else { return }`, to exit if it's anything but `MyAnnotations`.

Comment: `<court.MyAnnotations: 0x608000340e70>` //if successful                              and                                                                                         `<MKUserLocation: 0x60c00003f620>` //If found nil @Rob

Comment: its working sir @Rob ,thank you sir, i have another question sir,,I can't tap again the map pin if the title is still shown, how can I tap again to the map pin while the title is still showing?

Comment: @Rob can you add your answer in the ANSWER section so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THE FOLLOWING CODE:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return
    }

    let ibp = view.annotation as? MyAnnotations
    print(ibp!)
    ibp_id = (ibp?.court_id)!
    IdentifierCell = "pin_IBP"
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "map_ibp_info", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`

Comment: yeah I found out already its only from nil , same answer of sir @Rob

Comment: i have another question sir,,I can't tap again the map pin if the title is still shown, how can I tap again to the map pin while the title is still showing?

Comment: `the title is still showing` means the annotation is selected somehow. Then when you click it again, `didSelect` function doesn't fire because it is 'already selected'. You have to manually deselect the annotation by calling `mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: true)` once you're done doing what you want.